# set height and width of color-box automatically depend upon data up to certain limit

Tags: jquery-ui

My question is I created a color-box with fix inner-Width and inner-Height below code

```
$.colorbox({
    iframe: true,
    overlayClose: false,
    fixed: true,
    opacity: 0.50,
    href: "@Url.Action("RelatedCasesPopup", "RecordView", new { ID = @Model.Case_Id, area = "" })", inner-Width:870,
    inner-Height: 570,
    scrolling: true
});
```

I just want to change the size of color-box up to certain limit when data is more than it should show scroll-bar but if data is less than it re-size to smaller size automatically

Comment: `innerWidth` and `innerHeight` should have no dashes in them. The code, as it is in the question, *should* throw a syntax error

Comment: ok  i changed what u suggest but i want to resize according to data upto certain limit in colorbox what should i do for this.